# playlistItems for the uploads playlist not sorted according to publication date

Tags: youtube-api

I have a query:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=THE_UPLOADS_PLAYLIST&key=THE_API_KEY&fields=items/contentDetails/videoId

Is my assumption that the videos for the uploads playlist should be returned in publication date order incorrect?

Comment: 1) Include all query in question, don't use external links  2) You link returns `{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}` . It look like we haven't got right to see this link.

Comment: To run the query you need to replace THE_UPLOADS_PLAYLIST with the id of the uploads playlist. Also replace THE_API_KEY with a correct api key.

Comment: Better to give query results  in this question, see  "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My client does not want me to publish the complete query. And I don't think it is needed in order to understand my question. Are the videos for the uploads playlist ordered by publication date when using the playlistItem API call?

Answer (score 0):

According to this bugreport, https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6869, videos are ordered by relevance.